# Flux Concatenation does not return

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, reactive, spring-webflux

I'm experimenting with Spring Boot 2.0, webflux and reactiv Mongo repositories. I have two variants of first deleting and then adding data to a collection. In the first variant the thread blocks until the deletion is finished, in the second variant the adding of data is concatenated to the deletion.

Variant A

```
@GetMapping("init")
public String init() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Flux<Power> powers = Flux.range(0, 10000)
            .map(i -> new Power(i,
                    LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+1")),
                    rand.nextDouble()));
    powerRepository.deleteAll().block();
    powerRepository.save(powers).blockLast();
    return "ok";
}
```

Variant B

```
@GetMapping("init")
public String init() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Flux<Power> powers = Flux.range(0, 10000)
            .map(i -> new Power(i,
                    LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("+1")),
                    rand.nextDouble()));
    powerRepository.deleteAll()
            .concatWith((v) -> powerRepository.save(powers)).blockLast();
    return "ok";
}
```

Variant A returns, variant B not. What is the difference? What is the right way to combine two repository operations?

Comment: Basically what Greg wrote. The difference is due to the emission of values: `deleteAll()` terminates without emitting a value and concatenating the result during `deleteAll` execution. Concat executes while the parent publisher is executed which can cause undesired behavior. In general, return a reactive type (`Mono`, `Flux`) instead of a resolved type (`String`) to retain reactive behavior. Otherwise, you still block the calling thread. Spring WebFlux handles execution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain using .then calls if nothing better. Avoid block calls and instead return Mono.just("ok").

```
public Mono<String> init() {
    return repo.deleteAll()
        .then(() -> repo.save(...))
        .then(() -> Mono.just("ok"));
}
```

Make the endpoint return Mono.

Comment: In case you need to save a list of entities return Flux<String> as a response type and use .thenMany(() -> repo.save(powers)).thenMany(() -> Flux.just("ok"))